# Django view is broken when Ckeditor is added

Tags: python, django, django-forms, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Every think was working fine before - I have added Ckeditor to a existing model and I started getting this error. I don't understand whats the relation between Haystack, Ckeditor and ViewDoesNotExist.

The moment I remove this line `COURSE_CONTENT = models.TextField(default='What will be taught?')` in models.py then the view function is working fine, which tells thats there is nothing wrong with views.py.

**This is the error**
  https://db.tt/TWKu3N90
**More detailed error**
  https://db.tt/a8jbyM89

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your urls.py, forms.py and models.py? Further, is ckeditor working in Django admin for that model field?

Comment: I have not enabled admin view for this model and plz check the url for code https://gist.github.com/krishnateja/be312c5679f757dd031f

Comment: Code looks fine. Try adding a widget of ckeditor on a TextField on existing model TextField rather than changing into RichTextField(). Further, in your templates, add the ckeditor.js static file to render it

Comment: Can you please direct me towards doing it with any self help link.